# Qual o erro desse meu simples exercício de JS?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando executar o exercício prático do curso de JavaScript para iniciantes, mas não está dando certo. E eu não sei o porquê, o Inspetor também não aponta erros.

O exercício é sobre Condições (`if`, `else`). Na minha tentativa SEMPRE aparece o resultado else, mesmo tendo escrito "Brasil" no input.

Em quê eu errei?

Segue o código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PRÁTICA  </title>
</head>
<body>
    País: <input type="text" name="país" id="país">
    <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="verificar()">
    <div id="resultado"></div>

    <script>
        function verificar() {
            var país = window.document.getElementById('país')
            var res = window.document.getElementById('resultado')
            if(país == 'Brasil') {
                res.innerHTML = 'Você é brasileiro!'
            }else {
                res.innerHTML = 'Você é estrangeiro!'
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

A variável `país` é um elemento HTML, você tem que usar o atributo `value` do objeto `país`.

Tente isto:

```
if (país.value === 'Brasil') {
```

Comment: Obrigado! No caso com números não precisa, é isso? Se puder me tirar mais uma dúvida... O que eu faço se quisesse aceitar tanto Brasil como brasil (com inicial minúscula)? Eu tentei assim "if(país.value == 'Brasil' && 'brasil')", mas não deu certo

Comment: Por nada! Se puder marcar a resposta como resolvida, eu agradeço :)

Comment: Sim. Ainda precisa usar o `.value`, e no segundo caso, você tem que verificar da seguinte forma: `if (país.value == 'Brasil' || país.value ==  'brasil')`. Acontece que, se você usar o operador `&&`, a condição teria que ser Brasil e brasil ao mesmo tempo... E você tem que usar `.value ==` para cada teste :)

Comment: Opa, entendi! Muito grato pelas respostas! já vou marcar como resolvida :D